# How to remove my Grid corners

Tags: wpf, rounded-corners

My `Grid`:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="65" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="352" Background="Gray">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

How to make my corners transparent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background on the border and put the border around the Grid

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" Height="65" Width="352" 
    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8" Background="Gray">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```